# getElementById finds <DIV id="foo"> that's above it, but not below it

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've never taken a course in Javascript coding, nor read a book on it. Never had a *strong* need. But I just noticed the most bizarre problem that might explain many of my difficulties with JS over the years.

This works in FF 3.6:

```
<html><body><div id="foo"></div>
<script> var x=document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML="OK"; </script>
```

But oddly this does not work in FF 3.6:

```
<html><body>
<script> var x=document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML="OK"; </script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

In other words, Javascript code, which I was always told should be higher up in the file and preferably in the header, cannot see HTML elements that occur below it in the file.

While my test has clear results, I want to ask: Am I correct about this rule (that I have never seen stated before), or is this just an FF bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript may execute before the browser actually built the DOM-tree with the div tag.

To make sure JavaScript will actually find the element make sure to use an onReady function.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML="OK";
}
```

With your first code-snipped the div is in front of the JS, so the browser will probably build the DOM tree before it actually executes the JS (not guaranteed though, but it’ll probably always work for you).

In your second snipped you place the div behind the script tag, thus the JS is executed first, when the DOM-tree does not include the div element at all yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript code cannot see HTML elements that occur below it in the file.

JavaScript is executed during parsing. Unless you delay the execution (by assigning a function as an event handler), the element you are looking for simply does not exist when the script runs. This is expected behaviour.

> which I was always told should be higher up in the file and preferably in the header,

In general, [you shouldn't load JavaScript unless just before you actually need it to run](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom). It blocks parsing, so it delays the rendering of the page while it downloads and runs. In many cases, the `<script>` element should appear immediately before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's executing in the order in which it is parsed..

You need to execute that after the entire DOM has loaded.

To do this..

```
window.onload = function() {
   // do your stuff here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively, put your javascript code at the end of the page just before the `</body>` tag and it will find the element fine :)